# proc sql perform same operation over multiple columns

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with 20 columns all starting with the name `morb_`, which are all `1` or `2`, coded as `No` and `Yes`. There is an additional column called `Pat_TNO` which is the patient reference number. Patients have more than one row.

I wish to create a new dataset which summarises whether each patient has had at least one of each type of event. So far the code I have written works perfectly, but is there a way to simplify it using an array?

```
proc sql;
   select
      Pat_TNO,
      max(morb_1) as morb_1 format yn.,
      max(morb_2) as morb_2 format yn. /* etc etc */
   from morbidity
   group by Pat_TNO;
quit;
```

COumn names aren't `morb_1` and `morb_2`, rather `morb_amputation`, `morb_mi`, `morb_tia`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
proc summary data=morbidity nway missing;
   class pat_tno;
   output out=max max(morb_:) = ;
   run;
```